# Neo4j to Gephi import : Failed to invoke procedure Invalid UTF-8

Tags: neo4j, gephi

I tried to import my data from Neo4j into Gephi but it doesn't work.

I have the following result in Neo4j :

`Failed to invoke procedure` apoc.gephi.add`: Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xfb at [Source: (apoc.export.util.CountingInputStream); line: 1, column: 136]`

Comment: Those kinds of errors are usually a decoding error; You are trying a different decoding than the what your data were encoded in. Ie. your data were probably not encoded in UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, it looks like neo4j is **not exporting using UTF-8**, so that, I would check how neo4j is generating the output.

**Another possibility** is that, when neo4j writing the output, something went slightly wrong.
I got this very same problem in the past when concurrently managing content in a **file**.
A thread crashed and **closed "not correctly enough" the file**. I mean, when reviewing the file, everything looks pretty normal, but some characters have been introduced which are not UTF-8. A tool like **Atom** can help you.

Best